# Implementing CSP in an existing system containing third party libraries

Tags: css, hash, xss, directive, nonce

I've learn some about Content-Security-Policy, although not fully (and that's why I'm here), and now I want to implement CSP in a rather old existing project.

Problem is, many files has multiple javascript/css inlines. Both that I've created myself and some from third party libraries...

What is the best way to take care of these inlines, if any? There are plenty of files and I dont want to go into all the files and adjust them (if it's possible), especially not in the third party files.

From what I've understood, by using 'self' directive, it authorizes linked javascript files in the domain. Now some of the linked third party libraries in the project are containing inline css, or "innerHTML += someMarkUpCode;", which in turns gives
"Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:" in the browser.

I've also read you can use hash or nonce for inlines, Problem is; some third party files seems to be dynamic (like the example above), so I guess hashing cannot be used?
I've been looking into nonce, but it seems like it's not supported by IE? Not sure how it could be used with third party libraries either.
But I guess for constant pages hash or nonce could be used...

I dont want to use 'unsafe-inline' directive.

Have I missed anything obvious?

TL;DR:
What is the best way to manage third party libraries containing inlines when implementing CSP?

Comment: These are exactly the reasons why csp (or security in general) cannot really be retrofitted into an application, especially an older one. I don't think there is an easy answer to this.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?